# Formatting field data in phpmyadmin database column

Tags: mysql, sql, number-formatting

Im trying to change the display of numbers of a certain column in my database.
The table is called `member_records` and the specific field is called `userID`  (int type) and the data under `userID` varies in length(in terms of number of characters) but Im only interested in the last 7 digits.
Anyone with any idea how I can make the field `userID` display only the last 7 digits?

Comment: _varies in length(in terms of number of characters)..._ What is the type of the column? Int or Varchar? - BTW: this question has nothing to do with `phpmyadmin`

Comment: @B001its an int type of column

Comment: _Im only interested in the last 7 digits..._ So why don't you just store the last 7 digits

Comment: @B001 Because Im not the one doing the input. Thats user input

Comment: what have you done so far to achieve your output?

Comment: So you are saying that an integer column called UserID is generated by a user inputting something?

Comment: Hint: `right()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the modulus with 10,000,000 to extract the last 7 digits of an integer. For example,

```
create table member_records (user_id int);
insert into member_records values
(12359725),
(445),
(923587356),
(389475679);

SELECT user_id % 10000000 AS user_id
FROM member_records
```

Output:

```
user_id
2359725
445
3587356
9475679
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=be51b3a15d46eb11ac0b430971852da1)

Comment: Thank you! This has been very helpful